# Sum of two different cells in datagridview in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagrid

My datagridview has two columns:

```
Row1 - User; col1 - TimeIn; col2 - TimeOut.
```

Both `TimeIn` and `TimeOut` are filled with `DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();` through a Label which contains the time.

Basically, there is a user which enters a building and col1 gets the Time after the user check-ins, then when he gets out of the building and check-outs col2 gets the time too. Its first row. Col2 gets filled when they check out.

I've tried to convert the time to a number and then take the sum of col1+col2 to a Label outside the grid but I couldn't be productive. I'm new in C#.

Comment: You want to have the total time between TimeIn and TimeOut? or something else?

Comment: A DGV can have a column which displays the result of an *`Expression`*.  Your project went off the rails when you stored a `DateTime` as a `String`.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: I'm sorry for making this look unprofessional and stupid but this is my first time in here, I've read the policies but I thought I was okay. So yeah, I needed the total of TimeIn and TimeOut and I used DateTime, as I said im new to C# and I thought using DateTime is the way. Correct me with the best way to solve my problem. Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to get the difference between the two times?

Comment: Yes sir, difference between two times. I'm still trying to but didnt get a successful code til now.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you add a duration column, it looks something like this after the grid is bound.  The col2-col1 produces a TimeSpan which can be formatted.

```
foreach(DataGridViewRow row in yourDataGridView.Rows)
{
    row["Duration"] = (Convert.ToDateTime(row["col2"])-Convert.ToDateTime(row["col1"])).ToString("c");
}
```

The TimeSpan format of c produces a certain loop of the data, but you can format this content in other ways too.  Some examples of how to format timespans.

```
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-timespan-format-strings
```

Also, depending on your underlying data structure, you might want to instead assign the TimeSpan to the list before binding, but you have not provided this code.